# application shutdown in emulator after running

Tags: java, android-studio

Everytime i try to run the app the app stops after de loadingActivity.
When it try to run the MainActivity it stops.
My logcat looks like this.

```
03-18 20:41:11.242 11729-11729/com.example.valueapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-18 20:41:11.243 11729-11729/com.example.valueapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.valueapp, PID: 11729
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.valueapp/com.example.valueapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at com.example.valueapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Did you see that: `ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Project -> Clean

If this doesn't work you might actually cast something to an EditText somewhere.